# .htaccess - redirect query string with specific words to 404

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm like to redirect incoming query strings with certain trigger words to a 404.

background:

long story short.

- server got hacked, 64decode content injection
- cleared, incoming spam links using /? query string
- now attempting to redirect all query strings to 404 with exceptions:

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^.*\/wp-login\.php?(.*)   
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^.*\/wp-admin\/(.*)  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} . [NC]  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^wordfence_logHuman= [NC]      #### allow wordfence     
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^p= [NC]          #### allow post/page previews       
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^page_id= [NC]    #### allow cornerstone  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^s= [NC]          #### to allow for search page urls  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^ver= [NC]        #### to allow for .js and .css files that have version numbers  
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^rsd= [NC]        #### to allow for some feed urls  
RewriteRule (.*) /my-404.php? [L,R=404]         #### my-404.php is a dummy 404 page uri - it could be nearly anything
```

reference: https://sites.google.com/site/onlyvalidation/page/force-a-404-or-410-using-the-htaccess-file-on-apache-server

The blanket /? to 404 redirect breaks a lot of wordpress functionality. I feel like I should change the approach so that only certain spam words (vuitton, young, dildo, etc) would cause the 404.

This way I can maintain full wordpress functionality while blocking incoming query string spam that gets redirected to the homepage and indexed by google.

Thoughts/Help?

Comment: This is wrong approach. Collect a list of spam URLs and block only them.

Comment: The reason why I'm proposing this approach is because 1. there are thousands of url and 2. new urls are popping up literally everyday